# serialize cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks any patch available

Tags: magento2

Any Patch is available for below Issue i have not upgraded 
Security enhancements

> In general, we’ve removed serialize/unserialize from most the code to
>   improve protection against remote code execution attacks. We’ve
>   enhanced protection of code where use of object serialization or
>   unserialization was unavoidable. Additionally, we’ve increased our use
>   of output escaping to protect against cross-site scripting (XSS)
>   attacks.

So you need to inject \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json class for serialize and unserialize values.

use following code for serialize and unserialize values.

```
protected $serialize;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serialize
) {
    $this->serialize = $serialize;
}

public function serialize($value){
    return $this->serialize->serialize($value);
}

public function unserialize($value){
    return $this->serialize->unserialize($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this from .htaccess file?

```
# Extra Security Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

Google it for an explanation.

Comment: i need patch file which is related to serialise/unserialise